# Not able to convert into date in oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to convert the date field, but the year is not correct.

My code is:

```
SELECT to_date((ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) + 25), 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
FROM dual
```

Expected output is like `26/02/2018`, but I get `26/02/0018`.

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't apply TO_DATE function on a DATE datatype value, which is what SYSDATE is.

Saying that you have to compare the result of your query with another DATE datatype value will be just fine, as you'll compare two dates.

As of incorrect format you get: in *presentation* layer, you'd use TO_CHAR function and format the result anyway you want; for example:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    to_char((ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) + 25), 'dd/mm/yyyy')  val_1,
  3    to_char((ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) + 25), 'mon dd yyyy') val_2
  4  FROM dual;

VAL_1      VAL_2
---------- --------------------
26/02/2018 vel 26 2018

SQL>
```

Note that both values are *strings*, not dates. Moreover, see a strange VAL_2 month? It is in Croatian, but there's a way out of it:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    to_char((ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) + 25),
  3            'mon dd yyyy',
  4            'nls_date_language = english') val_2
  5  FROM dual;

VAL_2
--------------------
feb 26 2018

SQL>
```

or even

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = english;

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT
  2    to_char((ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) + 25), 'mon dd yyyy') val_2
  3  FROM dual;

VAL_2
--------------------
feb 26 2018

SQL>
```

but - once again - this is just to present data. There's nothing you should do with your code, except from removing TO_DATE function (optionally, you can alter session in order to see date the way you want it, but it won't change anything but visual appearance):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) + 25 val_3
  2  from dual;

VAL_3
----------
26/02/2018

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the date in a particular format, use `to_char()`:

```
SELECT to_char((ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) + 25), 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual
```

The result of:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -1) + 25 from dual
```

is a date and it is correct.  The problem is converting the date to a date.

Comment: i am trying to convert into date because i will be comparing one more date column with this output

Comment: SELECT  S_DATE
  FROM   test WHERE    
  
             to_date(S_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')   BETWEEN 
              
            ( SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(S_DATE, 'MM'), -1) + 25 from dual)  AND 
             ( SELECT TRUNC(S_DATE, 'MM') + 24 from dual)

Comment: though date is matching but output is not coming

Comment: @user3375647 . . . You don't need to convert a date to a date.

Comment: As per your comments assuming that S_DATE column in test table is of DATE datatype. Code should work after removing date conversation, since its not required. Also there is no need to use dual table. Try this - SELECT S_DATE FROM test WHERE S_DATE BETWEEN ( ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(S_DATE, 'MM'), -1) + 25) AND ( TRUNC(S_DATE, 'MM') + 24)